# Rails write regular expression to get folder name

Tags: ruby, regex, rspec

This is a simple question, I want to clean up carrierwave picture after the Rspec test.

The picture file is in `public/NewsletterImage_809abef471699025f5bb396d04dfd4f0"`, the string behind `NewsletterImage` will be a random string.

I want to get the folder name by `regular expression`, but it didn't work.

I've tried this

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/public/^NewsletterImage"]
=> []
Dir["#{Rails.root}/public/NewsletterImage.*"]
=> []
```

I am confused, because I use [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/sdD1ztrymX) and it can extract these names.

Comment: is `NewsletterImage` the folder name you want to extract?

Comment: The folder name will be `NewsletterImage_abc`, `NewsletterImage_def`or ` `NewsletterImage_xyz`. I need to get all of them.

Comment: try `/NewsletterImage_.+/` as your regex.

Comment: I found out `Dir["#{Rails.root}/public/NewsletterImage*"]` will work, but why others fail?

Comment: I am not sure this it correct to type, but `Dir["#{Rails.root}/public//NewsletterImage_.+/"] ` return empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Dir[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) doesn't take a regular expression, it takes a shell wildcard expression. These might look superficially similar, especially with `.*` being a common feature in both, but they're not the same.

If you want to use a regular expression you have to fetch all entries and then filter them with something like [`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep).

Comment: So `.*` accidentally  matches both regular expression. Thanks, I will try `grep`

Comment: Yeah, `.*` in wildcards means "a dot followed by zero or more of any character" while `.*` in a regular expression means "zero or more of any character". The confusion is understandable.